# Google Sign-In works fine on simulator but not on real device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift2, ios9.1

I'm testing with an iPhone 5 in **Swift 2.0, Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1** with a good wifi connection.

I have followed this tutorial ( http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/ ) and everything works fine on simulator but when I run this app on a real device using my iPhone 5 it opens the Google search App (with some registered accounts inside them) for handle sign in. It prompts the user to select an account. Once an account is selected, the google search app then asks the user if my app can access their information. Once a user clicks SIGN IN, 
After, when come back on the app code don't enter on this function:

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("idSegueContent", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

My main `ViewController()` class is this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    var contentViewController: ContentViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // MARK: Google SignIn Delegate Methods
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("idSegueContent", sender: self)
        }
    }


    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        contentViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "idSegueContent" {
            contentViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ContentViewController
        }
    }
}
```

If the Google search app is not installed, then Safari opens in the app just fine and once signed in, the delegate callback methods work just as expected.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @CalebKleveter: i updated my question. i replaced my `viewDidLoad()` function code with my whole `ViewController()` class.

Comment: @CalebKleveter: i can email you my project. it just a demo project to  Integrate Google Sign In into iOS Apps. Like i explained in my question i was following this tutorial [link](http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/) for more info you can see the tutorial's [link](http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/) .

Comment: @MuhammadQasim did you ever resolve this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally got it working after restarting my phone. (After hours of tests, checks, and re-organizing code!) Hopefully this simple solution saves someone else from the trouble.